# Value Error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (114,9) (8,) (114,9)

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to scale my inputs using StandardScaler and this gives me an error that

> Value Error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (114,9) (8,) (114,9)

First I removed the patients for the test dataset as follows,

```
test = patient.iloc[2092:,0:9].values
```

Then I scaled the test data as follows,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc=StandardScaler()
patient[['Age','Weight','Glucose_t-3','Glucose_t-2','Glucose_t-1','Carb_t-1','Insulin_t- 
1','Glucose_t-4']] = sc.fit_transform(patient[['Age','Weight','Glucose_t-3','Glucose_t-2','Glucose_t- 
1','Carb_t-1','Insulin_t-1','Glucose_t-4']])
data = patient.iloc[:,0:9]
```

Then after that I tried to transform the test data using the following code

```
test_data = sc.transform(test)
```

The above line gives the error. When I print the shape of the two arrays test and data it gives,

```
print(test.shape)
print(data.shape)


(114, 9) ------ test shape
(2206, 9) ----- data shape
```

The columns are same only the amount of records are different. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you fit transform the data on 8 columns - not 9. You're missing a column name.

1. 'Age',
2. 'Weight',
3. 'Glucose_t-3',
4. 'Glucose_t-2',
5. 'Glucose_t- 1',
6. 'Carb_t-1',
7. 'Insulin_t-1',
8. 'Glucose_t-4'